# A Metallic Riley

Tags: riddle, word

Since my previous Riley was quite successful, here's another one:

> The prefix allows you to eat what is old.
>   The suffix will make you think it is cold.
>   The infix is metal, as chemists should know.
>   Together they are controlling the flow.

I think it's time for a hint:

> The prefix sometimes is made of the infix.

Comment: Few possibilities - crevice, interstice, orifice...

Comment: But these don't fit the first and last clues.

Comment: Feedback: I'm stumped. Good one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Canalise

The prefix allows you to eat what is old.

> *Can* - a container for storing food over long periods

The suffix will make you think it is cold.

> *Ise* sounds like **Ice**

The infix is metal, as chemists should know.

> **Al** is the chemical symbol for aluminium

Together they are controlling the flow.

> To Canalise means *"to direct the flow of"*

Hint

> Cans are usually made of aluminium

Comment: Nice work, but I dont like the ising -> Icing part if that is indeed what OP was referring to. Icing to me is a type of topping for a cake

Comment: Actually I meant the infinitive form (“-ise” instead of “-ising”), but that's a detail, so I declare it solved.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes more sense actually. Don't know why I jumped there.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> Faucet 
>  (- tough one to come up with coming from europe where we call them taps)

The prefix allows you to eat what is old.

> Thaw out frozen food... sounds like Fau

The suffix will make you think it is cold.

> cet.... maybe like set - when a jam or jelly is made (fruit preserve) it should 'set' when it is cold (it has cooled down).

The infix is metal, as chemists should know.

> Ce - atomic symbol for Cerium, one of the Actinide metals if I remember correctly.  
>  Alternatively, the middle of the word sounds like 'ore' which is a mineral containing a metal.  
>  Alternatively, Au = gold.

Together they are controlling the flow.

> A Faucet (or tap) controls the flow of water from a pipe - or other liquid, or gas...

Comment: Actually that's the first time I encountered the word you suggest as solution — which should already tell you that it is not the word I was after. :-)

Comment: @celtschk ...  oh rats... thanks for rapid comment

Comment: sorry but it’s spelled “faucet”. Fawcett is a surname

Comment: @ferret: Ah, in *that* form I've actually seen it before :-) But it's still not the solution.

Comment: @ferret - thanks ... I was thinking it could be gold in the middle  - Au.., but of course the whole thing is not correct...